# mod_rewrite slash and header.php didn't include with slash in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I Need Help With My **.htaccess** file .. Now i have link like that http://www.afrogfx.com/20121028050853/Test.html
problem located with **Slash /** !! if you click on my link you will found link without style if remove slash you will get 404 Not Found Like That http://www.afrogfx.com/20121028050853Test.html
Try it !! 
**Here Is my .htaccess**

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ readmore.php?url=$1
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html/$ readmore.php?url=$1
```

**readmore.php**

```
    <?php
    include ('config/connect_to_mysql.php');
    $url=$_GET['url'];
    if($_GET['url'])
    {
    $url=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);
    $url=$url.'.html'; //Friendly URL 

    $sql=mysql_query("select * from posts where url='$url'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $title=$row['title'];
    $text=$row['text'];
    }
    else
    {
    echo '404 Page.';
    }

    ?>
```

**Problem Here**

```
    <?php
    include('styles/header.php');
    include ('styles/leftblock.php');
    include ('styles/mrnuleft.php');
    ?>






    <?php
    if($count)
    {

    echo "<h1>$title</h1><div class='text'>$text</div>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<h1>404 Page.</h1>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @Brendan Scarvell Thanks For You i Know if i load from root (CODE) Without incloud it's will be work but i need to incloud
    <?php
    include('styles/header.php');
    include ('styles/leftblock.php');
    include ('styles/mrnuleft.php');
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a path problem. When I go to the page with the slash it's including this:

`styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

So what it's trying to include is actually:

http://www.afrogfx.com/20121028050853/styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css

Try telling it to load from the root directory:

`/styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 0):

You can either make all of your header links absolute:

From:

```
<link href="styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To:

```
<link href="/styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can add right below your `<head>` tag:

```
<base href="/">
```

The problem is you have relative links for your styles and scripts. When the browser tries to request something like: `/20121028050853Test.html`, the **URI Base** is simply `/`. But when the browser requests `/20121028050853/Test.html`, the base becomes `/20121028050853/` and the browser will use this base and append all relative URLs to this base, thus `styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css` becomes `/20121028050853/styles/assets/css/bootstrap.css`, and you get no styles or scripts.